# Attempting to define a non fixed argument function in C

Tags: c

I'm trying this code just to get the basics of defining a function that takes un unknown number of arguments, becasue that function will call sprintf, in C.

So my code so far looks like this:

```
#include <QCoreApplication>
#include <QDebug>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

void debugMsg(const char *control_string,...);

char __errorLog[100];

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);

    debugMsg("Este es un mensaje de debug con 5 parametros %d %d %d %d %d",1,2,4,56,57);

    return a.exec();
}

void debugMsg(const char *control_string, ...){
    va_list argptr;
    va_start(argptr,control_string);
    sprintf(__errorLog,control_string,argptr);
    va_end(argptr);
    qDebug() << __errorLog;
}
```

NOTE: I'm using this in QtCreator as it is the fastest way that I had to get some very simple, pure C, code working in order to test out stuff I'm learning.

So this was taken form an answer to the very question I posed myself (how to create a function that takes many arguments).

The code kind of works as it produces as a result:

```
Este es un mensaje de debug con 5 parametros 1262382712 4 56 57 0
```

I think the va_start function takes my arguments "shifted" for lack of a better word so the very first argument passed to the sprintf function is not a 1 but some memory location (maybe the pointer for the control_string?) and the last is a 0 instead of 57.

So my question is, what am I doing wrong and how can I correct it?

Comment: `__errorLog` is a [reserved identifier](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.1.3): "All identifiers that begin with an underscore and either an uppercase letter or another underscore are always reserved for any use."

Comment: The use of `qDebug() << __errorlog;` is C++, not C.  However, names containing `__` are reserved in C++.  Ick!

Comment: Did not know, this. However it was just a proof con concept. I'll just use something else in the final product. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Rather than using `sprintf` directly, you need to use `vsprintf` which takes a `va_list` argument rather than taking values directly. The values you see in your output are some int representation (because `%d`) of a `va_list` (I guess it's a pointer), and then random memory (which is undefined behavior).

```
vsprintf(__errorLog, control_string, argptr);
```

See http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/vsprintf/

Comment: You're welcome. Also, consider using `vsnprintf`to avoid buffer overflows.